position of gsap element is not fixed after animation completes
See i have a circleAnimation and canvas component when i am completing my circle animation , it's position is not fixed it rolls down and intersects with other component i Want that after complete=ing circle animation it should remain fixed
I tried using the pin and position fixed property but it is not working
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/dist/ScrollTrigger";
import { useNavbar } from "../../layout"; // Adjust the path to your Navbar context

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

const CircleAnimation = () => {
  const { toggleNavbar } = useNavbar(); // Access toggleNavbar from context
  const circleRef = useRef(null);
  const svgRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Hide navbar when the animation starts
    toggleNavbar(false);

    const circle = svgRef.current.querySelector("circle");

    // Create the animation for the red stroke around the circle
    gsap.fromTo(
      circle,
      { strokeDashoffset: 1256 }, // Start with a full stroke offset (circle perimeter is 1256)
      {
        strokeDashoffset: 0, // Animate to 0 stroke offset
        duration: 3,
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: circleRef.current,
          start: "top top",
          end: "bottom top",
          scrub: true, // Smoothly animates the stroke as you scroll
          pin: true, // Pin the animation until complete
          onEnter: () => toggleNavbar(false), // Hide Navbar when entering the trigger area
          onLeaveBack: () => toggleNavbar(true), // Show Navbar when leaving back
          onLeave: () => toggleNavbar(true), // Show Navbar when leaving
        },
      }
    );

    // Clean up function
    return () => {
      ScrollTrigger.getAll().forEach((trigger) => trigger.kill());
    };
  }, [toggleNavbar]);

  return (
    <div
      ref={circleRef}
      className="h-screen w-screen bg-white flex flex-row justify-center items-center"
    >
      <svg ref={svgRef} height="500" width="500">
        <circle
          r="200"
          cx="250"
          cy="250"
          stroke="black"
          strokeWidth="3"
          fill="none"
          style={{
            transform: "rotate(-90deg)", // Rotate the circle to start at the top
            transformOrigin: "center", // Set transform origin to the center of the circle
            strokeDasharray: 1256, // Total circumference of the circle (2 * Math.PI * radius)
            strokeDashoffset: 1256, // Initial stroke offset to hide the red progress bar
          }}
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CircleAnimation;    

import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/dist/ScrollTrigger";
import { useNavbar } from "../layout"; // Adjust the path to your Navbar context
import CircleAnimation from "./(circleAnimation)/circleAnimation";

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

const Canvas = () => {
  const { toggleNavbar } = useNavbar(); // Access toggleNavbar from context
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Pin the Canvas component
    ScrollTrigger.create({
      trigger: canvasRef.current,
      start: "top top",
      end: "+=100%", // The end point of the pinning
      pin: true, // Pin the Canvas component
      scrub: true,
      position : fixed  // Smooth animation tied to scroll
    });

    return () => {
      // Cleanup function to kill all ScrollTriggers when the component unmounts
      ScrollTrigger.getAll().forEach((trigger) => trigger.kill());
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      ref={canvasRef}
      className="h-screen w-screen bg-white flex flex-col justify-center items-center"
    >
      <CircleAnimation />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Canvas;

